# Why would R barplot work but geom_bar wouldn't?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with a crime dataset in Rstudio Cloud. I have tidyverse installed. I want to use ggplot2 for a simple barplot. When I use this script for the barplot...I get a barplot

```
table(Providence$months_names2)
Occurances<-table(Providence$months_names2)
barplot(Occurances)
```

But when I try to use ggplot2 with this script

```
x11()
ggplot(data = Providence) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(Occurances))
```

I get the following error

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type table. Defaulting to continuous. 
> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7789): x

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = Providence) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(months_names2))`.

Comment: I swear I tried that earlier...but now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why Ian's solution worked (thanks Ian) but I couldn't get the barplot using the object, Occurances, that I had created in the example. (other than the incorrect spelling :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we have a data.frame, `Providence`:

```
set.seed(123)
Providence <- data.frame(months_names2 = sample(month.abb,500,replace = TRUE),
                         prov_name = sample(c("NL","PE","NS","NB","QC","ON","MB","SK","AB","BC","YT","NT","NU"),500,replace = TRUE),
                         type = sample(c("robbery","assault"),500,replace = TRUE))
head(Providence)
#  months_names2 prov_name    type
#1           Mar        PE robbery
#2           Mar        SK assault
#3           Oct        NB robbery
#4           Feb        ON robbery
#5           Jun        NU robbery
#6           Nov        BC assault
```

The `ggplot` function is designed to map parts of a graph to *columns* of the data. There is a `data =` argument and a `mapping =` argument. When you map a column to a part of the graph, it should exist in the data.

`ggplot` is intended to be used for data.frame data, not tables.

```
Occurrences<-table(Providence$months_names2)
class(Occurrences)
#[1] "table"
Occurrences
#Apr Aug Dec Feb Jan Jul Jun Mar May Nov Oct Sep 
# 41  39  36  35  36  48  43  42  41  39  51  49
```

You can see that the `x` variable is actually in the names of the table.

```
names(Occurrences)
 [1] "Apr" "Aug" "Dec" "Feb" "Jan" "Jul" "Jun" "Mar" "May" "Nov" "Oct" "Sep"
```

So technically, it is possible to use the table if you convert it to a vector and extract the names:

```
ggplot() + 
   geom_bar(aes(x = names(Occurrences), y = as.vector(Occurrences)), stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

However, the power of `ggplot` is in not having to do all that manipulation and instead using the data directly.

```
ggplot(data = Providence, aes(x = months_names2, fill = prov_name)) +
   geom_bar()
```

[image]

Here, the default `stat = "count"` of `geom_bar` takes care of the table business for us.